# Correct way to seed DB with users when using Web Api Identity and Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I have a MVC Wab API and I've started modifying it to include some of my own tables using a code first approach.

I'm having trouble with seeding the AspNetUsers table with initial data which then works with my (the default) token based authentication.

When I seed the database, the SecurityStamp field is not populated and it seems this is critical to the token based authentication. 
Registering an account via the AccountController generates this fine, however when I see the table via the code below, the security stamp is not populated...understandably so.

```
    context.Users.Add(new ApplicationUser
    {
        Email = "damo2@email.co.uk",
        UserName = "damo2@email.co.uk",
        PasswordHash = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword("Som3Pass!")
    });
```

There appears to be a [UpdateSecurityStampAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497579(v=vs.108).aspx) method which I assume will generate the Security Stamp, but I can't figure out how to call / used it while seeding. (I don't know what to do with  here..I'm still a novice)

Questions are:

1. What is the correct way to seed the user table when using MVC WebAPI & Individual accounts.
2. If I should be using the UpdateSecurityStampAsync method, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 2, The steps are:

Add / Update the users in the context.

Create a UserStore.  The UserStore is basically the data layer wrapper for ASP Identity. It controls how ASP Identity works with the database.

Create a UserManager.  The UserManager is basically the implementation of ASP Identity.  ASP Identity "out of the box" contains many methods, most of which are empty (exp: SendSMS, VerifyTwoFactorToken).  The developer is supposed to implement the methods they care about.

However, the UpdateSecurityStamp method is one of the methods with a default implementation. So we luck out.

Call UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(UserJustUpdated.Id).

```
  public override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
      //The UserStore is ASP Identity's data layer. Wrap context with the UserStore.
      UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);

      //The UserManager is ASP Identity's implementation layer: contains the methods.
      //The constructor takes the UserStore: how the methods will interact with the database.
      UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

      //Add or Update the initial Users into the database as normal.
      context.AddOrUpdate(
          x => x.Email,  //Using Email as the Unique Key: If a record exists with the same email, AddOrUpdate skips it.
          new ApplicationUser() { Email = "damo2@email.co.uk", UserName = "damo2@email.co.uk", PasswordHash = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword("Som3Pass!") },
          new ApplicationUser() { Email = "2ndUser@email.co.uk", UserName = "Jane Doe", PasswordHash = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword("MyPassword") }
      );

      //Save changes so the Id columns will auto-populate.
      context.SaveChanges();

      //ASP Identity User Id's are Guids stored as nvarchar(128), and exposed as strings.

      //Get the UserId only if the SecurityStamp is not set yet.
      string userId = context.Users.Where(x => x.Email == "damo2@email.co.uk" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SecurityStamp)).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

      //If the userId is not null, then the SecurityStamp needs updating.
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(userId);

      //Repeat for next user: good opportunity to make a helper method.
      userId = context.Users.Where(x => x.Email == "2ndUser@email.co.uk" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SecurityStamp)).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDetault();

      if (!string.IsNullOrempty(userId)) userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(userId);

      //Continue on with Seed.
  }
```

As far as question 1, there are many ways.  Which one is *correct* is a larger discussion.  Most efficient? most secure? least work?

The main problem with the seeding approach are having the passwords as plain text.  Your environment will determine if that is a serious concern or not.